# Code image generator

Tags: image, generator

a few weeks ago I saw a website with a powerful generator to create beautiful pictures of own source code files. The generator created images with variable effects like perspective transformations and depth of field, etc.

Typically I don't ask such questions in here but I googled more than 2hrs and I cannot find this generator anymore. I'm really going crazy - I know this site exists ...

Here's a sample picture of code made with this generator:

[image: awesome picture probably made with that generator I'm searching]

Thank you very much!
Waescher

Comment: I just tried searching for this for 15m and half the Google queries I put had this as the top result. For future people: http://instaco.de/

Comment: Thanks @EhsanKia, by closing the question, those guys imprudently removed the answers as well. What a waste considering more than 8000 users were here to find that link.